# High Sierra - Terminal "messed up"

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, bash

After a re-installation of macOS High Sierra on my MacBook Pro, I realised that the Terminal is kind of "messed up" (random substrings of the Terminal's current output are produced) when resizing the window (decreasing the width and increasing it again).

[image]
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Output of `echo $PS1 $PROMPT_COMMAND`

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Does the problem only occur *during* resizing or is the content messed up afterwards?

Comment: *How* did you reinstall High Sierra?  Clean install, or in place install/upgrade?  Out of curiosity, why were you reinstalling in the first place?  We’re you attempting to fix something?

Comment: @nohillside screenshots added in the original post. depending on how fast i resize the window, the substrings vary (first screenshot was taken after resizing the window fast, second one after resizing it slow).

Comment: @Allan i changed the hard drive of the macbook and did a clean install

Comment: @nohillside refering to your question: the content is messed up, eg i can copy & paste it

Comment: That‘s a bit hard to see from the small screenshot. Is there anything special in .bashrc etc?

Comment: It looks like you have some sort of custom prompt. Can you get a better screen capture? In addition to your bash profile as @nohillside mentioned can you post the output of `echo $PS1 $PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: @nohillside i didn't change anything in .bashrc

Comment: @Allan i added the output of the echo command in the original post

Comment: @keezar What's the output of `shopt` and `stty -a`?

Comment: Are you using Terminal or iTerm2?

Comment: Somewhere in your .bashrc or .bash_profile PROMPT_COMMAND is set with some function.  See if you can find it and remove it